# Finding Greatest Common Divisor through iterative solution (python 3)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, math

I am trying to find the great common divisor by using a function and solving it iteratively. Though, for some reason, I am not sure why I am not getting the right output.

The greatest common divisor between 30 & 15 should be 15, however, my output is always giving me the wrong number. I have a strong feeling that my "if" statement is strongly incorrect. Please help!

```
def square(a,b):
    '''
    x: int or float.
    '''
    c = a + b

    while c > 0:
        c -= 1
        if a % c == 0 and b % c == 0:
            return c
        else: 
            return 1

obj = square(30,15) 
print (obj)
```

Comment: Move your `else` to outside the while loop

Comment: the function square doesn't return anything

Comment: Why is this called *square*?

Comment: What @inspectorG4dget says: You execute a return on the first run of the loop.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget is right, if your 'if' fails you use else to return 1 always. also, no need to set `c` as sum, it can be just `min(a, b) + 1`, iterations from (a + b) till min of them are useless from the algorithm point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should return a value only if you finished iterating all numbers and found none of them a divisor to both numbers:

```
def square(a, b):
    c = a + b

    while c > 0:
        if a % c == 0 and b % c == 0:
            return c
        c -= 1
    return 1
```

However, the last `return` will be unneeded in this case, as `c` would go from `a + b` to `1`, and `mod 1` will always bring a common divisor, so the loop will always terminate with `1`, for the worst case.

Also, a number greater than `a` and `b` can **not** be a common divisor of them. (`x mod y for y > x yields x`), and `gcd` is the formal name for the task, so I would go with

```
def gcd(a, b):
    for c in range(min(a, b), 0, -1):
        if a % c == b % c == 0:
            return c
```

for iterational solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested to know that there is a common recursive solution to the GCD problem based on [the Euclidian algorighm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).

```
def gcd(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return a
    else:
        return gcd(b, a % b)

print(gcd(30, 15))
# 15
```

Comment: OP stated he wants an **iterative** way of solution.

Comment: and btw, `def euclid (m, n): return euclid(n, m % n) if n else m` should suffice.

Comment: @Uriel Your answer clearly explains how to fix his iterative solution. I thought that he might be interested to know about the Euclidian algorithm as an alternative.